# Expect.pm:expect() gives "Unexpected Subroutine" error

Tags: perl, expect.pm

I'm extremely new to Perl and struggling with something.  Recently, another developer left my company, and my boss has asked me to fix a Perl script that my former colleague wrote but did not document.  This script worked great in the past.  I mostly understand his code, but a call to `Expect.pm:expect()` confuses me.

The script is meant to scp a file off a remote server.  Here's my former colleague's code, slightly abridged:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

# Lots of use statements here, including:
use Expect;

# We set a lot of variables here...

# We use expect->spawn() to spawn an scp session into the remote machine
my $scp_exp = Expect->spawn("scp", "$account\@$remoteIP:$dir/$file", "$local_dir/");

# We set the parity
$scp_exp->raw_pty(1);

# We call expect() for the SCP session
$scp_exp->expect($timeout, [qr/.*[pP]assword:/, \&givePd, $pd],
        [qr/.*[pP]assword: /, \&givePd, $pd],
        [qr/100%/, \&closeExp],
        [qr/No such file or directory/, sub{exp_continue}],
        [qr/$prompt/, \&closeExp]);
```

Most of this I understand, but that last line (`$scp_exp->expect()`) is completely baffling to me.  I assume that when the script scp's to the remote machine, we have to give `expect()` a timeout, then prepare `expect()` for all the possible outputs the remote machine might give?  The [man page for expect()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/expect) talks about an array of `@matched_patterns`, but I don't fully follow that discussion.

When the script runs, I get this exact string as my output:

```
Password: Undefined subroutine &main::givePd called at /usr/share/perl5/Expect.pm line 759.
```

I'm assuming that my script executes just fine, but when `expect()` issues its commands on the remote machine, the "givePd" string confuses the remote host.  So `expect()` throws an error, and everything comes crashing to a halt.

BTW, the only references to string "givePd" are shown in the code excerpt, above.  So that's not a variable or something that was improperly set.

There's one more thing I should mention.  I am trying to run my colleague's script on a new Ubuntu machine, a machine that has never successfully run this script before.  In fact, when I ran the script for the first time, I realized that I needed to use `apt-get install` to install the Expect.pm module:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libexpect-perl
```

So I guess its possible I installed a newer version of the module?  Not sure.

Anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: @ikegami  ...a sub ref...  Huh.  Wow, that's really helpful information, actually.  Thanks, now I know what to look for

Comment: "a Perl script that my former colleague wrote but did not document" I've often tracked down that person and bought them enough beer to help me figure it out. It's not their problem anymore, but personal relationships tend to travel between employers  :)

Comment: Also, you note that you are setting things up in a new environment. Typically, I try to recreate the old environment first and ensure things are working there, then start updating things. Docker or something similar can help with that.

Comment: @briandfoy Yeah, I thought about the "bond over beer" solution.  Unfortunately, this former colleague works several states away.  Beer can only solve so many problems, alas

Comment: @briandfoy Yes!  Very wise to recreate the old env.  I have to get in the habit of doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\&givePd` produces a reference to the sub `givePd`. This is passed to `expect` to tell it to call `givePd` when certain strings are received from the child program. But just like the message says, and just like you said in your answer, you never defined `givePd`. (Same for `closeExp`.) So it's obviously going to fail.

Comment: That's very helpful!  So I should look for a variable or function called "getPd" elsewhere in the script?  I wonder if there's a secondary file that I missed...  Thank you!